# How to toggle browser_spellcheck dynamically in tinymce

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I've a custom toolbar button, which is used to toggle the browser's spell check. I've used

```
browser_spellcheck : true
```

in the initialization. Now if we press button, then i need to 'off' the spell check.

So, how can we set `browser_spellcheck` to `false` dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the init settings of TinyMCE dynamically - it simply does not allow that to happen.  If you need to change a setting like this you would need to use the `remove()` and `init()` APIs to reload the editor with new settings.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But, i'm looking for the way other than reinitialize.