# Enable or Disable the browser spellchecker function of tinyMCE

Tags: angular, typescript, tinymce

I have a custom toolbar button, which is used to toggle the browser's spell check.
I have set

```
browser_spellcheck : true
```

on the editor initialization. I need to turn 'off' the spell check when I press the custom toolbar button I made.

I am aware that we cannot change tinyMCE's init options after initialization. I am looking on a way to achieve my goal of having to toggle the spellchecking function via a toolbar button.

Also, I have already searched the site for similar questions and found this [How to toggle browser spellcheck dynamically in tinymce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320654/how-to-toggle-browser-spellcheck-dynamically-in-tinymce) but it currently has no answers. I can't comment on it so I posted a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You have mentioned:

> I am aware that we cannot change tinyMCE's init options after initialization.

...and `browser_spellcheck : true` is an init option.

Therefore, nothing within TinyMCE itself - including a toolbar button, which is defined upon init - will be able to change that init option, as the option cannot be changed without destroying and re-rendering the editor with new configuration.

If you take this desired functionality *outside* of TinyMCE, you could potentially create an external button that:

- Grabs all of the current content of the TinyMCE editor
- Saves that content
- Destroys the current editor instance
- Initializes a new instance with desired configuration changes
- Reloads the content into the editor

Comment: Thanks, actually that is what I intend to do as my last resort. For now I am still open for other ways. Currently I am looking into how the spellcheck was implemented on tinyMCE. Since it is currently using the browsers's spellcheck feature, maybe there is a way that I can alter the editor's DOM to toggle this on or off.